# Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure Version 1.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache first

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, gac

I have Windows 8 and Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone installed in WMWare virtual PC.

For some time ago I have downloaded `WindowsPhonePowerTools` (Click once application). It has been running well.

The VS Express 2012 has been notifying me that there are some updates available. Last Tuesday I installed the updates. VS Express runs well, but WindowsPhonePowerTools doesn't anymore.

It says: Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure Version 1.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAc) first.

I searched the web to find a way to have a look in GAC. The guides are for Windows 7, for. [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c.aspx)

How can I have a look in GAC in Windows 8? 
 How can I install Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure Version 1.0.0.0 in GAC?

I have just downloaded the latest version of the WindowsPhonePowerTools but the problem still exists.

Thanks if anyone can help me.

Comment: No-one here could help me. Luckily I found the application site and the author of the application fixed the problem in it. Thanks to him for a very quick fix.